# HTML5: How do I stop triple mouse clicks from selecting other html elements when clicked on canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

So I have a unity WebGL game, and underneath my canvas I have some links to business related sites, support/social etc.

Our game generally needs the user to click a lot, and its annoying right now that when the user triple clicks anywhere in the body, these link images at the bottom get highlighted and selected.

It doesn't actually effect gameplay, but its annoying.

Here's the structure of the page. (urls removed for security)

```
<img id="titleLogo" src="..." >
<canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" height="639px" width="1024px"></canvas>
<div id="loadingBox">
    <div id="bgBar"></div>
    <div id="progressBar"></div>
    <p id="loadingInfo">Loading...</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <table id="links">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="..." target="_blank"><img id="likeus" src="..." ></a></td>
        <td><a href="..." target="_blank"><img id="faqhelp" src="..." ></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><a href="..." target="_blank"><img id="hippo" src="..." ></a></td>
        <td><a href="..." target="_blank"><img id="kong" src=".." ></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use user-select as described here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

```
.noSelect{
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

in css and add the noSelect class to everything when the canvas is up